# I can't get markers from firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

When i start thist activity my app stopping.I need get coordinates from databes and place marker. I don't know where is problem.

My database:

[image]

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    f_database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map data = (Map) child.getValue();
                Map mCoordinate = (HashMap)data.get("Blog");
                double latitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("lat"));
                double longitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("lng"));
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("pedik"));
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: please update with error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this to retrive lat and lng

```
f_database.child("Blog").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {         
                double latitude = (double) (snapshot.child("lat").getValue());
                double longitude = (double) ((snapshot.child("lng").getValue());
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("pedik"));
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank's this real help me))

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to fetch all the **Blog**'s children then you should put your reference on `DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blog");`

When you put your firebase reference on `DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`. This will fetch all the nodes of the database, in your case **Blog** and **users**. If you need the info of blogs you don't need to fetch the data of users. This is a very poor code practice when it comes to **firebase**.

Secondly, as @Benjith binja suggested you can fetch all the **Blog**'s children to fetch latitude & longitude. Alternatively, you should make a Blog Object and fetch the data. It is a good practice. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Blog Object:

```
class Blog {
    public String desc,id,image,time,title,uid,username;
    public Double lat,lng;

    public Blog(String desc, String id, String image, String time, String title, String uid, String username, Double lat, Double lng) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.time = time;
        this.title = title;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

The firebase listener would look something like this:

```
DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blog");
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                // Get Blog object and use the values to update the UI
                Blog blog = snapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(blog.lat,blog.lng);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("pedik"));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
f_database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

Error must be occurring due to the wrong usage of Map. Here is how your code should look.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

mMap = googleMap;
f_database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map data = (Map) child.getValue();
            Map mCoordinate = (HashMap)data.get("Blog");
            //mCoordinate is a map with values of all the children of Blog
            for(String key: mCoordinate.keySet()){
                Map mCoordinateChildMap = (HashMap) mCoordinate.get(key)
                double latitude = (double) (mCoordinateChildMap.get("lat"));
                double longitude = (double) (mCoordinateChildMap.get("lng"));
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("pedik"));   
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```